# Synchronization does not work

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, calendar, htc-magic

- HTC magic
- Android 1.6

A couple of weeks ago the built in sync of mail, contacts and calendar stopped working. Sync is activated for all three and it seems to sync sometimes, but not all the time as it is supposed to do (it did). E.g. mail and contacts synced at 2:34am and calendar synced at 7:30am (but it's 10:11pm now).

Any ideas?

**Solution:**

I went with mlevits advice. I removed my account from the phone via the trick I described now in [How can I remove the default Google Account on my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1841) (the "clear-all-data" trick did not work and I did not want to factory reset the phone). After I reentered my account data the syncing works again. Thanks a lot mlevit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my knowledge of the Sync functionality on the Android it only syncs when it has something new on one of those services. It uses Push technology to send you the latest updates as soon as they become available.

If however new items are appearing in your mail, contacts and/or calendar and it's still not syncing then I would recommend you remove your Google account and re-add it again.

*NB. I did have an issue with Sync once where it just wasn't pushing any emails to my phone... it fixed itself after a couple of days.*

Comment: Remove my google account? Are you serious?

Comment: BTW: The is new stuff all the time which is not synced.

Comment: Remove the account then re-add it? I don't see what the problem is? You're not going to lose any data.

Comment: Now I get it. I thought you meant **deleting** my google account. I unlinked my account from the phone and relinked it and now the syncing works like a charme. Thanks a lot! (will update question)