# Android - Change Google account on Nexus S

Tags: google-account, samsung-nexus-s

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove the default Google Account on my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/how-can-i-remove-the-default-google-account-on-my-phone)

I tried different methods of changing the Google account on my Nexus S, all failed. Did someone manage to do this, without a factory reset?

Comment: As noted in the dupe (and Ryan's answer below), you normally have to do a factory reset.  EricShaefer's clever answer to the dupe looks like it might work, though, worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot change the "default" user account. This is the account tied to the market and other things by default. The only way to change it, is doing a factory reset.